# How to put a triangle gray corner on a ImageButton?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I have a square `ImageButton` defined in the `xml` whose source image may change programmatically.
Regardless of what's the image inside I want to **display a little gray triangle in the bottom right corner** (the goal is to suggest the user to click on the image and to pick another icon from a list). Here's an example I found on Marshmallow:

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: You could use a spinner with your custom layout instead of a ImageButton, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html?hl=es-419

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás thanks for your answer. If I'm not wrong using the `Spinner` I would be forced to use a dropdown menu! So I would prefer to use the `ImageButton` as I could define its behavior as I want.

Comment: use a `LayerDrawable`

Comment: Disable the spinner.Put that spinner inside relative layout.On click of relative layout perform the action

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
           <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/image_holder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/chosenThing"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/chosen_image"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/corner"
                        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chosenThing"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/chosenThing"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/chosenThing"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_corner"
                        android:tint="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="bottom|right" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where did you get `@drawable/ic_corner`? Shouldn't I use a `FrameLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` if the goal is to overlap the two `ImageViews`?

Comment: @Robb1 No, you need to use `RelativeLayout` because of `layout_align..` attributes, that will allow second image to stretch relative to first image. 

`@drawable/ic_corner` - just some image for your corner. Draw it in paint, or do as XML (if it's possible).